# Can't able establish connection in activemq server?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm newbie to activemq server.I have downloaded activemq 5.8 version.I have used following code for creating and sending messages to activemq server.

```
private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;
    private static Connection connection = null;

    public static boolean testessages(String message){

            Session session = null;
            try {
                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                    new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
                connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                connection.start();
                session = connection.createSession(false,
                        Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                Destination destination = session.createQueue("orderjson");
                producer = session.createProducer(destination);
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
                message.setText(msg);   
                producer.send(message);
                return true;

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if(session != null){
                        producer.close();
                        session.close();
                        connection.close();
                    }
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            return false;
        }
```

If i run the above code cant create the connection.After debugging the code issue is, the code wasnot executed when its comes to **connnection.start()**. The Error message

**there's no thread suspension support**
How to resovle this error?
please someone help me?

Comment: You forgot to set the `brokerUrl` on the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`. Not sure if this is the only problem...

Comment: Thanks.I have tried after setting brokerUrl also failed.Again same error.